# Creating 3 tables into excel using Openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to create 3 tables in an excel file, however they are created one below the other. I am looking to place them next to each other. I suspect append is causing the tables to be created under each other. Can you please help me!

```
sh2.append(["Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)"])
for column in small:
    sh2.append(column)
tab = Table(displayName="Small_Companies", ref="A1")

sh2.append(["Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)"])
for column in medium:
    sh2.append(column)
tab = Table(displayName="Mid_Companies", ref="D1")

sh2.append(["Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)"])
for column in large:
    sh2.append(column)
tab = Table(displayName="Mid_Companies", ref="G1")
```

Comment: Hello, I think your `ref` should be something like this: `ref="A1:D1"`

Comment: Hello T0ny 1234, I just tried ref="A1:B1", same result, tables are created one below the other.

Comment: Please post an MCVE

Comment: Append places things below. Why are you surprised about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use `zip` to combine three lists and append them all together. I don't know if these three lists are of same size so I first append them to same length. Also your call to Table function is not quite right, the ref parameter requires a range of the table. I just assume you have 5 rows.

```
max_length = max(max(len(small), len(medium)), len(large))
small += [""] * (max_length - len(small))
medium += [""] * (max_length - len(medium))
large += [""] * (max_length - len(large))
sh2.append(["Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)","Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)","Market Sector", "Assets (in GBP)"])
for (c1,c2,c3) in zip(small,medium,large):
    sh2.append(c1+c2+c3)
tab1 = Table(displayName="Small_Companies",ref="A1:C5")
tab2 = Table(displayName="Mid_Companies",ref="D1:F5")
tab3 = Table(displayName="Large_Companies", ref="G1:I5")
sh2.add_table(tab1)
sh2.add_table(tab2)
sh2.add_table(tab3)
```

Comment: Hello whilrun, thank you, but I am not looking to append the tables. I require these 3 tables to be saved in an excel file at a cell location of choice.